# error C3499: a lambda that has been specified to have a void return type cannot return a value

Tags: c++, lambda, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am using the following lambda and I am getting this error. I can't figure out why the compiler doesn't like what I am doing.

```
std::string captchaWord(6, 0);
std::generate(captchaWord.begin(), captchaWord.end(), []() {
    unsigned int num = Randomizer('z' - 'a' + 1 + '9' - '0' + 1);
    char ch = num + 'a';
    if (num >= 'z' - 'a' + 1)
    {
        ch += '0' - 'z' - 1;
    }
    return ch;
});
```

By the way, Randomizer is a function with the following signature:

```
unsigned int Randomizer(unsigned int);
```

This is the error message I get:

error C3499: a lambda that has been specified to have a void return type cannot return a value.

Comment: Message `lambda that has been specified to have a void return type` is clear. You have to specify a return type. E.g. `[]() -> int ...`

Comment: Your code is correct and compiles fine with [g++](http://ideone.com/V5cVBK) and VC12. Please specify which compiler are you using.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Visual Studio? For me the code compiles just fine. (Also see http://cpp.sh/4hbi)

Comment: @BetaCarotin you are indeed correct. I am aware of this and using your suggestion indeed work. I am trying to figure out why I am forced to specify the so obvious return value in this lambda function.

Comment: @Abhijit I am using vc 2013

Comment: Refer to [this article](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) for an explanation. Also, please accept an answer below since your problem seems to be solved.

Answer (score 4):

You have to specify the return type:

```
[]() -> char {
// your code;
}
```

The automatic deduction only works if the whole lambda consists **of a single return statement only** (in C++11), otherwise, you need to specify the type. See also the documentation on [lambda on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). In C++14, the rules allow other statements before the return.

Comment: You mean *"single statement"* and not *"single return statement"*.

Comment: No, I mean single return statement, same language as used in http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#975 - "the return type of a lambda can be deduced only if the body of the lambda consists of a single return statement"

Answer (score 2):

Your code is valid according to the current standard, C++14. But in C++11, a lambda with no specified return type has a return type of `void` unless its body consists of a single return statement.

It seems your compiler doesn't support the latest standard. To fix the problem, specify the return type:

```
[]()->char { .... }
```

Comment: But before C++11, the standard didn't support lambdas.

Comment: @Abhijit Thanks, I meant before C++14. Fixed.

Comment: Yes, but the definition in C++11 was: "if the body consists of nothing but a single return statement with an expression" -- i.e. no other statements!

Comment: @Anteru I think you're referring to a comment that got removed.

Comment: Yes, seems he removed it .. for the record, the original comment was that the lambda contained only one return, which is not sufficient for C++11 auto type deduction.